# `FuturesUnordered` does not satisfy `Stream`?

Tags: rust, stream, future

I want to implement a `Stream` that is based on a [`FuturesUnordered`](https://docs.rs/futures/0.3.14/futures/prelude/stream/struct.FuturesUnordered.html), which again is supposed to evaluate `async` functions with a return type of `Result<SomeEnum>`, though for simplicity of the argument let's assume it's only a `Result<f64>`. As `async fn`s eventually return `Future`s, I assumed that the following way would be how I have to define my struct:

```
use anyhow::Result;
use futures::{Future, Stream, stream::FuturesUnordered};
use std::{pin::Pin, task::Poll};
use pin_project::pin_project;

#[pin_project]
pub struct MyDerivedStream<'a> {
    #[pin]
    from_futures: FuturesUnordered<&'a (dyn Future<Output = Result<f64>> + Send)>,
}

impl Stream for MyDerivedStream<'_> {
    type Item = Result<f64>;

    fn poll_next(
        self: Pin<&mut Self>,
        c: &mut std::task::Context<'_>,
    ) -> Poll<Option<<Self as Stream>::Item>> {
        let this = self.project();

        this.from_futures.poll_next(c)
    }
}
```

The problem I'm running into now is that for some reason the `poll_next` function on the `FuturesUnordered` fails to compile due to not satisfying `Stream` trait bounds. (See for yourself on [this Playground example](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=24945b7535dbed2622446dd3e21460fb)):

```
error[E0599]: the method `poll_next` exists for struct `Pin<&mut FuturesUnordered<&dyn futures::Future<Output = std::result::Result<f64, anyhow::Error>> + std::marker::Send>>`, but its trait bounds were not satisfied
  --> src/lib.rs:21:27
   |
21 |         this.from_futures.poll_next(c)
   |                           ^^^^^^^^^ method cannot be called on `Pin<&mut FuturesUnordered<&dyn futures::Future<Output = std::result::Result<f64, anyhow::Error>> + std::marker::Send>>` due to unsatisfied trait bounds
   | 
  ::: /playground/.cargo/registry/src/github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823/futures-util-0.3.14/src/stream/futures_unordered/mod.rs:55:1
   |
55 | pub struct FuturesUnordered<Fut> {
   | -------------------------------- doesn't satisfy `_: futures::Stream`
   |
   = note: the following trait bounds were not satisfied:
           `&dyn futures::Future<Output = std::result::Result<f64, anyhow::Error>> + std::marker::Send: futures::Future`
           which is required by `FuturesUnordered<&dyn futures::Future<Output = std::result::Result<f64, anyhow::Error>> + std::marker::Send>: futures::Stream`
```

I'm struggling to understand the problem here. For all I can see `FuturesUnordered` does implement `Stream`, so what is the actual issue here? Is is the `&'a dyn Future` - and if so, how else would I need to define the type here to make this work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`&'a dyn Future` does not implement `Future`, which is required by `impl Stream for FuturesUnordered`. One solution would be replacing `&'a dyn Future` by `Pin<&mut 'a dyn Future>`:

```
use anyhow::Result;
use futures::{Future, Stream, stream::FuturesUnordered};
use std::{pin::Pin, task::Poll};
use pin_project::pin_project;

#[pin_project]
pub struct MyDerivedStream<'a> {
    #[pin]
    from_futures: FuturesUnordered<Pin<&'a mut(dyn Future<Output = Result<f64>> + Send)>>,
}

impl<'a> Stream for MyDerivedStream<'a> {
    type Item = Result<f64>;

    fn poll_next(
        self: Pin<&mut Self>,
        c: &mut std::task::Context<'_>,
    ) -> Poll<Option<<Self as Stream>::Item>> {
        let this = self.project().from_futures;

        this.poll_next(c)
    }
}
```

It's necessary to mutably borrow the items in `FuturesUnordered`, this becomse evident by checking out the `Futures::poll` function which takes `self: Pin<&mut Self>`. The implementation of `Stream for FuturesUnordered` needs to poll the wrapped items in order to determine when a new item can be yielded, which is not possible with shared references.

Without the `Pin` around the `&mut Future`, it would be possible to `mem::replace` the wrapped future and cause that `Future` to never be actually polled.

This is a great resource to learn more about Pinning: https://fasterthanli.me/articles/pin-and-suffering

Comment: This solved the issue with the polling, but now I'm running into the problem of how to actually add items into the `FuturesUnordered`, as they are still required to be references to somewhere and I would primarily call the functions that return the futures within the local scope of `MyDerivedStream`... however, that's obviously out of scope for this question, so I have accepted this answer as-is and may set up another one if I can't figure out a solution myself.