# Do I have to use Pin when returning a boxed trait object from an async method?

Tags: asynchronous, rust, traits

```
async fn execute(&self, partition: usize) -> Result<Pin<Box<dyn BatchStream + Send + Sync>>>;
```

Comment: You don't need `Pin` for any async fn. The compiler does it automatically when needed.

Comment: @ChayimFriedman You do need pins if you're returning boxed futures, because otherwise they can't be awaited in contexts that are themselves pinned. (The pinning _requirement_ is what the compiler inserts automatically.) For example, code in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67400017/1600898) or [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68883807/1600898) does require the box contents to be explicitly pinned, otherwise it wouldn't compile.

Comment: @user4815162342 Oh I didn't see it returns a stream

Comment: @ken I believe the answer to your question is: yes, if you want to await it, you'll need to pin it. You can also return the box and let the caller pin it, but since you're returning a box anyway (so you're already allocating), there's no harm in replacing `Box::new()` with `Box::pin()` and thereby making the return value awaitable. The pin wrapper adds no run-time cost, it's a purely static construct.

Answer (score 1):

In general: No. If you have a function in the form `async fn f() -> Box<dyn Trait>`, there is no need for `Pin`.

---

However, returning a [`Future`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/future/trait.Future.html) or [`Stream`](https://docs.rs/futures/0.3.17/futures/stream/trait.Stream.html) is a special case. So if `BatchStream` is an alias, or supertrait, or just mimics the `Stream` trait, then the `Pin` is likely necessary for the return value to be useful.

See other Q&As that explain where `Pin` is needed with `Stream`s:

- [How to use map for Box<dyn Stream<Item=()>>?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61264860/how-to-use-map-for-boxdyn-streamitem)
- [Traits returning a trait: In some cases works, in others it doesn't](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64324868/traits-returning-a-trait-in-some-cases-works-in-others-it-doesnt)
- [`FuturesUnordered` does not satisfy `Stream`?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67280903/futuresunordered-does-not-satisfy-stream)